# How to play iOS standard "Tweet sent" sound programmatically?

Tags: ios, audio, twitter

I am using TWTweetComposeViewController for tweet composing.

Then I send tweet manually this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14067278/440168

How can I play standard "Tweet sent" sound notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sound is pretty similar: http://soundjax.com/reddo/51828%5EWHISTLE.mp3

You can play it like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *path        = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", NSBundle.mainBundle.resourcePath, @"whistle.mp3"];
NSUrl *url            = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.whistleUrl error:&error];

player.numberOfLoops = 0;
player.volume        = 0.4;

if (player == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    return;
}

[player play];
```